# HttpResponseRedirect creates invalid redirect URL

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, python-2.7, redirect

I am a Django newbie. I am doing following in my view:

```
if user_profile.key_expires < timezone.now():
        form=RegForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('appname/index.html',{'form':form,'expire':True})
```

Basically, if the account activation key has expired, redirect to homepage with expire as `True` so that I can show a message that says the link has expired. Problem is, I get this URL on redirect:

```
/confirm/<activation_key>/appname/appname/appname/....... (repeats)
```

This is a very long and repetitive URL. What am I doing wrong here. If this question is too basic, in my defence, I tried to find proper way of redirecting so that URL looks nice and clean but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a slash before your path to use absolute url. Django here is trying to use relative path. Which end up in the same endpoint in your application, and loop again.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/appname/index.html',{'form':form,'expire':True})
```

Comment: One question though, the redirect doesn't seem to be passing `{'form':form,'expire':True}` to the page. Any reason why?

Comment: @Maxsteel you are using a static html file, that's why

Comment: @Maxsteel you **cannot** redirect with data. A redirect is a response with a 302 status code and a url which the browser then makes a request to. If you want to keep any data you need to store it in the database / user session / cookies / some other storage of your choice and retrieve it later on.